# InvalidOperationException when joining on a composite key

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I have a LINQ query that throws an InvalidOperationException at runtime when calling ToList(), and I'm trying to figure out a way around it, if possible, without having to break the join up into separate where clauses.

The lines in question are 3 and 4 in the example below. loan_id is non-nullable type decimal, ti_disb_id is non-nullable type short. When I split these up into separate statements, there is no exception when calling ToList(). However, it seems to make more sense together, so if there's a solution I'd love to hear it. :)

```
        var baseQuery = (from a in context.ti_disbursements
                         join b in context.disbursement_schedule
                             on new {a.loan_id, a.ti_disb_id} equals
                                new {b.loan_id, b.ti_disb_id} into ab
                             from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join c in context.business_associates
                             on a.ba_id equals c.ba_id into ac
                             from c in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join d in context.investor_loan
                             on b.loan_id equals d.loan_id into ad
                             from d in ad.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join e in context.loan_information
                             on d.loan_id equals e.loan_id into ae
                             from e in ae.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join f in context.loan_balances
                             on e.loan_id equals f.loan_id into af
                             from f in af.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join g in context.ti_information
                             on e.loan_id equals g.loan_id into ag
                             from g in ag.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             loan_id = a.loan_id,
                             ti_disb_id = a.ti_disb_id,
                             ti_freq_id = a.ti_freq_id,
                             ti_disbursements_stop_code = a.ti_stop_code,
                             tax_account_number = a.tax_account_number,
                             ti_disb_due_dt = b.ti_disb_due_dt,
                             ti_expire_dt = b.ti_expire_dt,
                             ti_disb_amt = b.ti_disb_amt,
                             schedule_id = b.schedule_id,
                             ba_name = c.ba_name,
                             inv_bank_cd = d.inv_bank_cd,
                             inv_cd = d.inv_cd,
                             inv_group_cd = d.inv_group_cd,
                             loan_name = e.loan_name,
                             prin_bal = f.prin_bal,
                             ti_bal = f.ti_bal,
                             ti_information_stop_code = g.ti_stop_cd,
                             non_escrowed_type = a.non_escrowed_type,
                             ba_type_id = a.ba_type_id,
                             bill_received_dt = a.bill_received_dt,
                         });
```

The exception message:

> InvalidOperation Exception was unhandled by user code
>
> > The cast to value type 'Int16' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Run the query on the database to see the result and which columns are null.  That should give you a hint towards where the null is coming in.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely the exception has already provided all of that information (assuming it's actually being thrown from line 3 or 4 of that query), it's saying one of the `ti_disb_id` values is null.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That's the funny thing, none of the values are actually null. I looked at the database values and even used the query that's _supposed_ to be generated. Whether it _actually_ uses that query, I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, long story short, after much debugging I discovered that the problem was that I was using LEFT JOIN behavior instead of INNER JOIN behavior.

Specifically, the calls to DefaultIfEmpty() were creating rows which resulted in null values for schedule_id, which was of type non-nullable short (Int16), causing the exception. By taking out these DefaultIfEmpty() calls, the bad rows were not included, and the problem was solved, since schedule_id will never receive a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on Garrison's comment, I suggest you use the context Log property.
Open a `StreamWriter`, and assign to to `context.Log`. It will give you the exact SQL query that is run on the database, and you can run it and see where the problem is.

Comment: The exception is saying that one of the ti_dsib_id values is null, no need to look at the query.

Comment: @kobigurk Still figuring out how to grab the SQL, but here's what I have so far:
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType13`20[System.Decimal,System.Int16,System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int16],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Int16,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Int16],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int16],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a second look at your database. The exception is saying that one of those shorts is coming back as null (`a.ti_disb_id` or `a.ti_disb_id`). If necessary you can put an `if` statement within the query or use the null coalescing operator.

I think changing `new {a.loan_id, a.ti_disb_id}` to `new { loan = a.loan_id, disb = a.ti_disb_id ?? 0}` will solve your problems. The null coalescing operator is basically saying if this value is null then use the provided default value. In order to use it, assignment is required (I tried just doing `a.ti_disb_id ?? 0` but it won't compile) which is why I put in the property names. Reference doc is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Comment: Just tried this. For some reason it won't compile using the null-coalescing operator ??, so I changed it to use the ternary operator ? and replace with a 0 if null. Tested on both ti_disb_id and loan_id, but the exception is still thrown. They're non-nullable anyway, so they shouldn't have null values to begin with. Most odd.

Comment: @MacSigler that is unfortunate. Are you sure the error is coming from one of those lines? I believe any attempt at using that style of initialization will fail if you have a `null` value. The compiler has to infer the types and it cannot infer a type for null. I think if I were still trying to debug this I would personally start looking at the select statement. It's also creating an anonymous type so assignment with null will also cause a failure there.

Comment: Turns out it's the schedule_id, not ti_disb_id, causing the exception. Looking into it further.

Comment: @MacSigler assuming `b.schedule_id` is null at the point you do assignment the same solutions apply.